# List<type> parameter in asp mvc controller action returns null and not an empty list

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP MVC 3 with jQuery.ajax to post array values with traditional:true. This works fine with an array that has values. My only problem is that if the array is empty in the js then the value passed into the respective parameter in the controller action is always null. How can I get the mvc to return an EMPTY list rather than NULL so that I don't have to check for null all over the place to use LINQ?

Javascript Code

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/Foo/BarAction",
    type:"POST",
    traditional:true,
    data:{myParam:[]}
}):
```

C# ASP MVC Code

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult BarAction(List<string> myParam)
        {
            //myParam is null, and not an empty list
        }

}
```

Comment: Could you post some code please

Comment: I just added an example in my edit above!

Answer (score 1):

To return an empty list, you need to at least initialize it. So, before you return it, you'll need:

```
myParams = new List<string>();
```

Comment: You missed the point that the ASP.MVC routing handles the parsing of the POST array and uses reflection and convention to map those values to the controller action. The javascript array, if it has values, will get automatically converted to a List. If I had sent {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50} and my controller action had BarAction(string firstName, string lastName, int age), the routing engine would handle the type conversions and find the appropriate parameters to call. I'm wondering how I can get the framework to pass non-empty collections as a default for empty arrays!

Comment: And to clarify, at no point do I ever actually call fooController.BarAction(new List<string>()). MVC does that by convention automatically through routing.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying now. In that case, you might want to look into a custom model binder. Familiar with those?